# Building smaller cordova app with crosswalk lite but without the first run loading screen?

Tags: cordova, crosswalk

I have developed a cordova app and I tried to make the app size as small as possible.
The size without crosswalk is 2.16mb, which is quite satisfactory.
However I ran into some performance problems and compatibility issues (e.g. StatusBar and android back button not working on some of the devices, cannot select camera option when opening file selection, etc.)

By using [crosswalk](https://github.com/crosswalk-project/cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview), performance problems and most of the compatibility issues are solved, but the apk size has grown to 22.8mb, which I think is a pretty scary size for an app with such normal functions...
By using crosswalk lite (lite mode in the plugin above), the apk size is approx 11-12mb, but it comes with a loading screen, which shows the process of decompressing crosswalk library, during first run. It sometimes causes timeout problem when loading index.html and most importantly, it really looks unprofessional. These drawbacks are really awful to me (I believe that is also awful to the user).

So what can I do? I've tried my best to delete the unnecessary files in the app. If this cannot be resolved, I think I will look into other tools like Xamarin or even learn to use native tools and give up cordova when developing my next app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that shows the process of decompressing crosswalk library during first run is that your app can't load any web page until this procedure is finished, so there must be some way to prevent the user from proceeding. This is Crosswalk-lite's inevitable limitation. If you're using Cordova, there's nothing can help now. But if you use the [embedding API](https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/apis/embedding_api.html) of Crosswalk, you can make the dialog not to be displayed (but you still have to wait for it to finish).